# How to get partition of quicksort to produce the correct and expected output?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

This concerns "a software algorithm" from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in this case the quicksort sorting algorithm

This is a practice coding question(non competition) from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort1

Basically you're supposed to take in a list, say

```
4 5 3 7 2
```

and partition around the first element, in this case 4. The expected output is

```
3 2 4 5 7
```

However the output I am getting is

```
2 3 4 7 5
```

Here is my code for doing the partitioning(based off the learning friendly version from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-27/20-sorting3-merge-quick.pdf slide 16)

```
static void partition(int[] ar) {
       int toPartitionAround = ar[0];
       swap(ar, 0, ar.length - 1);
       int index = partition(ar, 0, ar.length - 2, toPartitionAround);
       swap(ar, index, ar.length - 1);
       printArray(ar);
   }   
   static int partition(int[] ar, int left, int right, int toAround) {
       while(left <= right) {
           while(ar[left] < toAround) {
               left ++;
           }
           while(ar[right] > toAround) {
               right --;
           }
           if(left <= right) {
               swap(ar, left, right);
               left ++;
               right --;
           }
       }
       return left;
   } 

   static void swap(int[] arrayNums, int index1, int index2) {
       int temp = arrayNums[index1];
       arrayNums[index1] = arrayNums[index2];
       arrayNums[index2] = temp;
   }
```

Is there a modification I can make to this to match the expected output? Am I technically still getting a possible correct output because my output does follow the property elements to the left of the pivot are less than the pivot and elements to the right of the pivot are greater than the pivot?

What I do is assign the pivot, move it to the back of the array and then partition the rest of the array around the pivot (from index of 0 to length - 2). With this input, one swap happened when going through the array(3 and the 5). Then when I get index from the result of the partition, I swap the pivot with that result, meaning I swap 4 and 5.

Do I follow a similar process to get the expected output? I can't see what to replace.

Comment: Upon observation of the problem and the output produced by your program, it is obvious as to what the problem is: `In the new sub-array, the relative positioning of elements should remain the same, i.e., if n1 was before n2 in the original array, it must remain before it in the sub-array. The only situation where this does not hold good is when p lies between n1 and n2`

Comment: @Smac89 How would this edit this code to do that though? I get that 3 and 2 should still be relatively positioned, 2 after the 3

Comment: I will post an answer soon, but the problem is with the way you are swapping

Comment: Correctness is a matter of definition - for the partition step of quicksort, I'd suggest the output is correct if it allows the entire sort to produce correct output. Expectations are in the eye of the beholder … You might want to look into _stable quicksort_.

Comment: Yeah stable quicksort is the just the definition of preserving the relative order right?

Comment: But @greybeard why would you want relative though? The only thing you should care about is the sorting. You would never want the 2 to come after the 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @greybeard's and @Smac89's comments, I realized I needed a stable form of quicksort, stable as in "preserving the original order of the input set, where the comparison algorithm does not distinguish between two or more items"(https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/247440/what-does-it-mean-for-a-sorting-algorithm-to-be-stable)

To me a stable sort doesn't really make sense for this run because the comparison algorithm does distinguish between 3 and 2, but oh well. Can someone clarify this?

The solution I came up with to maintain relative was creating two ArrayLists, one for holding values less than or equal to the pivot and one for holding values greater than the pivot. This way relative positioning is preserved.(2 will come after the 3, just like in the original list). Then I move the values from the two ArrayLists along with the pivot back into the original pivot.

Here is my solution in code if anyone is having troubles with this

```
 static void partition(int[] ar) {
      List<Integer> smallerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      List<Integer> biggerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int toPartitionAround = ar[0];
      for(int c=1;c<ar.length;c++) {
          if(ar[c] <= toPartitionAround) {
              smallerValues.add(ar[c]);
          } else {
              biggerValues.add(ar[c]);
          }
      }
      for(int c=0;c<smallerValues.size();c++) {
          ar[c] = smallerValues.get(c);
      }
      ar[smallerValues.size()] = toPartitionAround;
      for(int m=0;m<biggerValues.size();m++) {
          ar[m + smallerValues.size() + 1] = biggerValues.get(m);
      }
      printArray(ar); 
   }
```

Comment: `To` [committedandroider the need for] `a stable sort doesn't really make sense for this run because the comparison algorithm does distinguish between 3 and 2, but oh well. Can someone clarify this?` - not without knowing what _this_ is. If the order of records in an intermediate state is immaterial for the end result, what _is_ the bother?

Comment: A set of integers. The whole point of quicksort is to sort integers. It has to distinguish 3 and 2

Comment: Quicksort does work. Have a look at the discussion for this hackerrank challenge, thou.

Comment: I know it works, but why would you care about the relative order? The only order you should concern yourself is the sort order.

Comment: It wasn't exactly me expressing dissatisfaction with any order, relative (to what?) or not. Stable sort is about not changing the order of records _with equal sort key_. I have no idea whatsoever as to what came over idlecool@hackerrank to put up the challenge the way s/he did.

Comment: @greybeard Yeah stable ordering wouldn't make sense here. If you have two 2s, which have equal sort key, you shouldn't care what order they appear in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a little confusing one isn't it. All I did to solve that question was create 2 separate lists, one to store elements lower than pivot and another to store elements higher than the pivot. Then, you just print out the values. This is the way preserve the order of elements and you do an "in-place" sorting. But it consumes memory as well.